# click() not working on other page of data table

Tags: jquery

I need to delete user from a mySQL row. My "Delete" button works only on the first page, but when I change page it no longer works, [as you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFD2B.png). This is the code I use for delete:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#large').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      "bSortable": false,
      "aTargets": [-1]
    }]
  });

  $(".lnk").click(function() {
    if (confirm("This user will be deleted. Press ok to confirm.")) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "deactivate-user.php",
        data: {
          "user": $(this).attr('id')
        },
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == "Error") {
            $("#msg").html("Error occured while removing user! Please try after some time.");
            $("#msg").addClass("red-box");
            $("#msg").css("display", "block");
          } else {
            $("#msg").html("User has been removed successfully.");
            $("#msg").addClass("green-box");
            $("#msg").css("display", "block");
            $("#main-table").html(data);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<td>
  <a href="add-credit.php?user=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" name="credit" class="btn btn-primary credit">Credit</a>
  <a id="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger lnk">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Where is my error?

Comment: what does your console say? any error there??

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler, as the delete button is removed and then re-created when the page changes

Comment: have try the delegated event handler changing the code `$(".lnk").on( "click", "a", function() {` but continue to not work